# Filtering out entries in a database search result that have an error

Tags: python, performance, hash-map

Note: I based my solution on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38621915/find-duplicates-in-python-list-of-dictionaries)

I have this list of dictionaries.

```
[{'checking_period': datetime.timedelta(0, 74327, 365993),
  'error_margin': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'frequency_periods_num': 4955.157732866666,
  'last_task_run': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 11, 51, 40, 406007),
  'level': u'info',
  'past_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 29, 12, 772000),
  'present_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 30, 27, 772000),
  'task_frequency': datetime.timedelta(0, 15),
  'task_name': u'daredevil',
  'worker_host': u'vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64'},
 {'checking_period': datetime.timedelta(0, 74335, 406302),
  'error_margin': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'frequency_periods_num': 3716.7703151,
  'last_task_run': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 11, 51, 32, 365698),
  'level': u'info',
  'past_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 29, 7, 772000),
  'present_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 30, 27, 772000),
  'task_frequency': datetime.timedelta(0, 20),
  'task_name': u'hulk',
  'worker_host': u'vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64'},
 {'checking_period': datetime.timedelta(0, 74337, 418150),
  'error_margin': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'frequency_periods_num': 1651.9426255555554,
  'last_task_run': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 11, 51, 30, 353850),
  'level': u'info',
  'past_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 28, 42, 772000),
  'present_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 30, 27, 772000),
  'task_frequency': datetime.timedelta(0, 45),
  'task_name': u'deadpool',
  'worker_host': u'vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64'},
 {'checking_period': datetime.timedelta(0, 74372, 582736),
  'error_margin': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'frequency_periods_num': 1239.5430456,
  'last_task_run': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 11, 50, 55, 189264),
  'level': u'info',
  'past_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 28, 27, 772000),
  'present_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 30, 27, 772000),
  'task_frequency': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'task_name': u'joker',
  'worker_host': u'vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64'},
 {'checking_period': datetime.timedelta(0, 74330, 390651),
  'error_margin': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'frequency_periods_num': 1238.8398441833333,
  'last_task_run': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 22, 11, 51, 37, 381349),
  'level': u'error',
  'past_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 28, 27, 772000),
  'present_ts': datetime.datetime(2017, 6, 23, 8, 30, 27, 772000),
  'task_frequency': datetime.timedelta(0, 60),
  'task_name': u'joker',
  'worker_host': u'vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64'}]
```

It is returned from a query to a db.

As you can see, there are 2 dictionaries for `'task_name':'joker'` . One with `'level':'info'` and one with `'level':'error'`.

My goal is to create a final dictionary that will not contain the dictionaries that have the 'info' value , when there is one with 'error' value (when both have the same 'task_name' value). Note that the order of the tasks does not matter and that for every `task_name` there can be only one task each of each `level`, because the preceding SQL code already takes care of this.

My working code is the following:

```
a = get_task_logs(table=task_run_logs, worker_hostname="vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64") #The dictionary comes from this function


# for li in a:
#     print li #debug
print "---------------------------------------------------"

from collections import defaultdict
items = defaultdict(list)
for row in a:
    items[row['task_name']].append(row['level'])  #make a list of 'level' values for each 'task_name' key

# pprint.pprint(items) #debug

for key in items.keys():
    if len(items[key]) > 1:  #if there is more than one 'level'
        newValue = [level for level in items[key] if level == 'error'] #decided which of the list items to keep
        items[key] = newValue  #put that new value back into the dictionary

# pprint.pprint(dict(items)) #debug

final_data = []
for el in a:
    for key in items.keys():
        # print el['task_name'], key, "---", el['level'] ,items[key][0] #debug

        if el['task_name'] == key and el['level'] == items[key][0]:
            #print el #debug
            final_data.append(el)
print final_data
```

I was wondering if there is a more efficient/elegant way of doing the whole procedure, and especially the last part that I have a for loop inside another.

Comment: @Graipher No, the order is irrelevant. Every record is a task with a unique id that executed. The first time it may execute ok [so `info`], then throw an exception [so `error`] and then ok again [`info` again]. I want to isolate the last time it run and threw an exception.

Comment: I edited your question to include the additional information you supplied. Feel free to edit it again if I worded it in a wrong way.

Comment: No problem. It is fine!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can do it in one pass, instead of having to iterate over `a` (which I called `events` in the rest of this answer, because readable variable names are always better) twice, once to get the dictionary and once to print the values. First, I made your code actually re-usable, that means, I turned your `print` statement into a `yield` statement, so that it now is a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) of events which have no error. Afterwards I wrapped it in a second function that just consumes the generator into a list, so I can time the two afterwards. Otherwise this is your code as posted:

```
def iter_filter_out_error(events):
    items = defaultdict(list)
    for row in events:
        # make a list of 'level' values for each 'task_name' key
        items[row['task_name']].append(row['level'])

    # pprint.pprint(items) #debug

    for key in items.keys():
        if len(items[key]) > 1:  # if there is more than one 'level'
            # decided which of the list items to keep
            newValue = [level for level in items[key] if level == 'error']
            # put that new value back into the dictionary
            items[key] = newValue
    # pprint.pprint(dict(items)) #debug
    for el in events:
        for key in items.keys():
            # print el['task_name'], key, "---", el['level'] ,items[key][0]
            # #debug

            if el['task_name'] == key and el['level'] == items[key][0]:
                yield el


def filter_out_error(events):
    return list(iter_filter_out_error(events))
```

Instead of this, I would go over the input list once and put the events into a dictionary. Whenever you find an `error` event, store its `task_name` in a set so we can skip any later task_names which would overwrite them. Afterwards just return the `values` of that dictionary:

```
def filter_out_error_graipher(events):
    """
    Takes a list of event dictionaries and filters out
    all events for which an error level event exists.
    """
    error = set()
    events_out = {}
    for event in events:
        task_name = event['task_name']
        if task_name in error:
            continue
        elif event['level'] == 'error':
            error.add(task_name)
        events_out[task_name] = event
    return events_out.values()
```

*Now tested to actually produce the same output as the OP's code :)*

On my machine this takes about 1.56\$\mu\$s compared to your code, which takes 5.33\$\mu\$s. You would have to test it on larger inputs to see which scales better, but I would assume my code, because of the single pass.

Note that I added a [`docstring`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) to explain what the function does as well as used more readable variable names, which is recommended by Python's official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Very true about the variable names! :] I'll study your solution and report back.

Comment: Note: instead of doing a simple print in the end , I tried to append the `el` that passes the checks in a new list and it runs out of memory [never returns anything].... :\

Comment: @KostasDemiris well, that depends on how many events you actually pass through this...But in the end, if a later error can invalidate a task that came before, you will always have to keep them all in memory or pass all events twice.

Comment: @KostasDemiris Have a look at my edited code. Later events always overwrite earlier events with the same `task_name`, except if there was a task with an error level, then tasks with that name are always skipped.

Comment: I was trying to edit it myself in order to understand it :] . Thanks it works  perfectly and it is definitely more elegant and concise. I'm pretty sure that it will be more scale-able due to the single pass.

Comment: Quick question....Why do you use a set to store the task_name ? Wouldn't a plain list be the same?

Comment: @KostasDemiris Because `in` is on average \$\mathcal{O}(1)\$ for a `set`, but \$\mathcal{O}(n)\$ for a `list`. Have a look at this handy [time complexity site](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Answer (score 4):

- Try to keep assumptions in your code to a minimum. This code has quite a few assumptions, and so becomes confusing on what it should output.
- In your second loop it assumes there are only two levels, one of which has to be 'error', this is unintuitive. What makes this worse, is that it's fairly easy to show your intent here. Take:

  ```
  for task_name, levels in items.items():
      item[task_name] = next((level for level in levels if level == 'error'), levels[0])
  ```
- Your third loop should really remove the forth loop from within it. This is as your first if shows that you should really just index `items`.

  ```
  for task_name, level in items.items():
      if el['task_name'] == task_name:
          ...
  ```

  Instead in \$O(1)\$ time you can use:

  ```
  level = items[el['task_name']]
  ```
- Please don't leave debugging comments in your code, if you want to debug use `logging`. If this is due to you getting it working, please remove all the comments.

And so this could be cleaned to:

```
from collections import defaultdict

tasks = get_task_logs(table=task_run_logs, worker_hostname="vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64")

task_levels = defaultdict(list)
for row in tasks:
    task_levels[row['task_name']].append(row['level'])

for task_name, levels in task_levels.items():
    task_levels[task_name] = next((level for level in levels if level == 'error'), levels[0])

final_data = []
for task in tasks:
    level = items[task['task_name']]
    if task['level'] == level:
        final_data.append(task)

print final_data
```

From here it's clearer that, you should probably instead assign `task` to `task_levels` to remove the need for the final loop.
And you could also make this a function, which could be:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def get_error_or_first(tasks):
    task_by_name = defaultdict(list)
    for row in tasks:
        task_by_name[row['task_name']].append(task)

    for tasks in task_by_name.values():
        yield next((task for task in tasks if task['level'] == 'error'), tasks[0])

tasks = get_task_logs(table=task_run_logs, worker_hostname="vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64")
get_error_or_first(tasks)
```

If you wanted to optimize it more you'd get Graipher's code, however I think in this case you should KISS, as there is no longer the \$O(n^2)\$ loop. And both this and Graipher's run in \$O(n)\$.